# What simple fixed version images I can use with circleCI?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to use a plain linux image like alpine that is a fixed version

I am trying to find simple images I can use.
I have spent a lot of time on CircleCI's site on pages such as

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/tutorials/
and
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config/#section=configuration

but every configfuration I find seems to be targeted at a specific language or setup.  I just want a plain linux shell with bash.  Ubuntu seems a bit large, hence me avoiding it.  Are there other linux distributions which are a bit lighter but do have tools like bash and curl built in?

I finally found using

```
  - image: alpine:latest
```

and

```
command: |
  apk add bash curl-dev
  echo Hello, world.
```

worked.

Are there other basic images I could use?
For instance is there a fixed version rather than justv 'latest' so I could ensure it works in the future and I am not surprised by change.

Comment: What would you do with an empty distribution image?  There is a whole catalog on https://hub.docker.com/ and https://docs.docker.com/samples/#library-references, but you almost always build an application using a Dockerfile and run that.

Comment: Alpine is a very good choice, and still the smallest around. RE: "in the future and I am not surprised by change" - even if you use a specific version, such as V3.8 or V3.9, it is not guaranteed to remain unchanged, since packages may be updated to more recent version. As an example, recently OpenJDK 8 was bumped to the latest version in all Alpine versions starting V3.5.